# Composition of step function with linear one.

Tags: functions

Suppose that $s$ is a step function, and $f(x)=mx+k$. How to prove that $s(f(x))$ is step function also?

Edit:

Definition of step function:

Function $s$ defined on $[a,b]$ will called a step function is there exist a partition $P$ of $[a,b]$, $P=\{a=x_0,...,x_n=b\}$ such that $\displaystyle s_{|{\large{(x_{i-1},x_i)}}}=t_i$, for some $t_i\in \Bbb R$.

Comment: Can you state the definition of [step function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Step_function) you're using, please?

Comment: I edited my post.

Comment: I took the liberty of changing $f(x)=mx+n$ to $f(x)=mx+k$ as the $n$ might cause some confusion with the other $n$ below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints: The step functions are finite linear combinations of
$$s_a\colon x\mapsto\begin{cases}0 & x<a \\ 1 & x\geq a\end{cases}$$
$$\hat{s}_a\colon x\mapsto\begin{cases}0 & x\leq a \\ 1 & x> a\end{cases}$$
$$c\colon x\mapsto 1$$
Now the only thing you have to show is that $s_a\circ f$, $\hat{s}_a\circ f$ and $c\circ f$ are step functions. In proving this you might want to consider $m<0$, $m=0$ and $m>0$ separately.

Exempli gratia:
Let $m>0$, then
$$s_a\circ f\colon x\mapsto s_a(mx+k) = \begin{cases}0 & mx+k<a \\ 1 & mx+k\geq a \end{cases} = \begin{cases}0 & mx<a-k \\ 1 & mx\geq a-k \end{cases}$$
Since $m>0$, $mx<y$ if and only if $x<\frac{y}{m}$, thus
$$s_a\circ f\colon x\mapsto \begin{cases}0 & x<\frac{a-k}{m} \\ 1 & x\geq \frac{a-k}{m} \end{cases} = s_{\frac{a-k}{m}}(x)$$
and we conclude $s_a\circ f = s_{\frac{a-k}{m}}$.

The other cases are mostly similar.

Comment: Could you show me one case where $m>0$ and $s_a\cicr f$?

Comment: Ok. I'll add it to my answer.